# In GWT, how can I serialize/unserialize a Place using JSON in its tokenizer?

Tags: json, gwt, tokenize

I would like to create a standard Tokenizer for my places in GWT.

To do so, I would like to use the json format. Something like this :

```
public String getToken(T place) {
  return transformToJSON(place);
}

public T getPlace(String token) {
  return (T)transformJSONToObject(token);
}
```

I can't find a way to implements transformToJSON and transformJSONToObject. I've tried to use the JSONParser of GWT but it's quite limited to JavascriptObject (and Places are not JavascriptObject).

How can I achieve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really want to put JSON into your URLs?!

Anyway:

```java
public String getToken(MyPlace place) {
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
   obj.put("id", new JSONString(place.getId());
   return obj.toString();
}

public MyPlace getPlace(String token) {
   JSONObject obj = JSONParser.parseStrict(token).isObject();
   return new MyPlace(obj.get("id").isString().stringValue());
}
```

You can achieve the same using AutoBeans; in any case: copy things in and out of your place.

As an alternative, you can of course have your Place be backed by a JSONObject/AutoBean:

```java
class MyPlace extends Place {
   public static class Tokenizer implements PlaceTokenizer<MyPlace> {
      public String getToken(MyPlace place) {
         return myPlace.jsonObject.toString();
      }
      public Place getPlace(String token) {
         return new MyPlace(JSONParser.parseStrict(token).isObject());
      }
   }

   private final JSONObject jsonObject;

   public MyPlace() {
      this(new JSONObject());
   }

   public MyPlace(JSONObject jsonObject) {
      this.jsonObject = jsonObject;
   }

   public String getId() { return jsonObject.get("id").isString().stringValue(); }

   public void setId(String id) { jsonObject.put("id", new JSONString(id)); }
}
```

**Note:** All of the above works much better with AutoBeans; error handling is a PITA with JSONObject, and it doesn't make for very readable code either.

Some kind of code-generator can help here if you have a lot of places.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way how to (de)serialize any objects to JSON with GWT.

1) Define class extending JavaScriptObject with protected constructor

```
public class PlaceData extends JavaScriptObject {

    public PlaceData () {
    }
```

}

2) Add native getters and setter for fields

```
    public final native String getId() /*-{
        return this.id;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getToken() /*-{
        return this.token;
    }-*/;
```

3) Define somewhere mapping methods like those

```
public static getPlace(PlaceData placeData) {
    Place place = new Place();
    place.setToken(placeData.getToken());
    place.setId(placeData.getId());
    return place; }

public static getPlaceData(Place place) {
    PlaceData placeData = new PlaceData();
    placeData.setToken(place.getToken());
    placeData.setId(place.getId());
    return placeData; }
```

4) And for converting string to JavaScriptObject use native eval() function.

```
public static native JsArray<PlaceData> jobs(String jsonArray) /*-{
    return eval(json);
}-*/;

public static native PlaceData objects(String jsonPlace) /*-{
    return eval(json);
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I know that. The problem is that Place in GWT must extends the abstract class Place and not javascriptObject. So your solution cannot be done.